# Can literal_eval(f'{}') be misused to execute code from an outside source?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just curious if this is a risk at all, I can't think of a way a user might be able to cause this to happen... but it seems worrisome.

```
>>> import ast
>>> help(ast.literal_eval)
Help on function literal_eval in module ast:

literal_eval(node_or_string)
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
    and None.
```

`ast.literal_eval(f'{os.remove("dontdelete.txt")-hello-world}')` will execute the file deletion. Is there any risk that this could be used against an application? What does

> "Safely evaluate an expression node"

mean?

Comment: `f'{os.remove("dontdelete.txt")-hello-world}'` is getting evaluated *before* it gets passed to `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks! Turns out you can not eval `ast.literall_eval('f\'{y}\'')` which keeps it safe

Answer (score 4):

The reason [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is defined in this way is that it's a specialized function in the `ast` module, not a magic function designed to be used for all kinds of other purposes, so you're expected to have at least skimmed the `ast` docs if you're using it.

`literal_eval` can take either an `ast.Node` representing a parsed expression, or a string that, when given to `ast,parse`, produces such a node.

Then, as long as the expression only uses "the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`", it will evaluate the expression; otherwise, it will raise an error.

---

So, if you pass it the string `'os.remove("dontdelete.txt")-hello-world'`, well, when you parse that, you get a `BinOp` expression, which is not one of the kinds of expression nodes that `literal_eval` accepts, so it immediately rejects it with a `ValueError`.

---

And if you pass it the string `"""f'{os.remove("dontdelete.txt")-hello-world}'"""`, when you parse that, you get a `JoinedStr` expression node with a bunch of nodes inside it that `literal_eval` also doesn't accept (it's worth doing an `ast.dump` to see exactly what those nodes are, if you don't understand how f-strings work), so it's going to reject it with a `ValueError` again.

---

But what if you pass it the string `f'{os.remove("dontdelete.txt")-hello-world}'`?

Well, that string gets evaluated by the interpreter before it even gets passed to `literal_eval`.

In most scenarios, that's going to raise an exception before `literal_eval` can even be called, so `literal_eval` is completely irrelevant. For example:

- If `os` is not imported, you get a `NameError`.
- If the file doesn't exist, you get a `FileNotFoundError`.
- If `hello` or `world` don't exist, you get a `NameError`.
- If `hello` exists but is any normal kind of value, because `remove` returns `None`, you get a `TypeError` about trying to subtract whatever type `hello` is from `None`.

In some of those scenarios, the file is removed, of course. But since `literal_eval` never even got called, it's hardly relevant here. You could do the same thing with `print` instead of `literal_eval`, or just nothing at all.

But what if `os` is imported, and the file exists, and `hello` is an instance of some type with an `__rsub__` that accepts `None`, and `world` is an instance of some type that can be passed to the `__sub__` of whatever `hello.__rsub__` returned? Then `literal_eval` will get called with whatever that `sub` returns. If it's a string or an `ast.Node`, it will even evaluate it. And maybe that would be some other dangerous string? But in that case, `literal_eval` will raise a `ValueError` on that dangerous string, so no additional harm is done.